# linq null refactoring code

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, refactoring, null

i have code

```
public List<Files> List(int? menuId)
{
    if (menuId == null)
    {
        return _dataContext.Files.ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        return _dataContext.Files.Where(f => f.Menu.MenuId == menuId).ToList();
    }
}
```

is it possible to make it only one line like return _dataContext.Files.Where(f => f.Menu.MenuId == menuId).ToList();?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public List<Files> List(int? menuId) {
    return _dataContext.Files.Where(f => menuId == null || f.Menu.MenuId == menuId).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the "logical OR" operator (`||`) :

```
public List<Files> List(int? menuId)
{
    return _dataContext.Files.Where(f => !menuId.HasValue || f.Menu.MenuId == menuId).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can put the null check inside the lambda function:

```
return _dataContext.Files.Where(f => menuId == null || f.Menu.MenuId == menuId.Value).ToList();
```

However, if performance is any concern then your original version is preferable, because this version would unnecessarily call `.Where()` when menuId is null. (It would probably be a negligible difference in most cases, though.)